# How do I do Axton the Commando's speed glitch?

Tags: borderlands-2

The exploit was featured in the [AGDQ 2014 Borderlands 2 four-players co-op speed-run](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2YYwM1coOU#t=25m46). I think it involves a skill of Axton (the Commando) that speeds up his [ADS](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Aim-Down-the-Sight-%28video-games%3B-aka-Aim-Down-the-Scope%29-%28ADS%29.html) movement,  which is manipulated and stacked to allow him to move at Sanik speed.

Comment: +1 to offset the unexplained -1. Seems like a legit question to me.

Comment: @Snailer That's exactly how you should **not** be voting.  http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system

Comment: That may be true, but can we just say that I'm voting on the post's quality? He's provided a relevant link. For whatever reason I upvoted, it's deserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed glitch is accomplished this way:

- You must use **Axton** (*duh*)
- You must have at least **1** point in **Expertise**, in the *Gunpowder* skill tree
- You must have at least two weapons to do this
- You must be in a Multiplayer session, and you **CANNOT** be host

Some other tips when starting this:

- Having a full backpack will make the process of the glitch much more quicker and simplified
- Having more points in Expertise (either via mods or skill points) will make the process quicker to achieve.

Going over the skill in general:

> **Expertise**
>
> - Weapon Swap Speed: +14% per level
> - Aim Speed: +14% per level
> - Movement    Speed (while aiming): +7% per level

How our glitch works is this.  Since Expertise will only increase the movement speed while aiming down the sights (or scoping in), you need to have one gun on the ground, and one gun in your hands.

Normally, if you find a weapon, you can press E to grab it, just like any other item.  Now, if you hold E when you find a weapon, you will automatically equip it.

So to perform this glitch, we need Axton to switch weapons while aiming down the sights.  This is why previously, I have mentioned that you should have a full backpack, so that pressing E doesn't collect the weapon on accident.

## Steps:

1. Aim down the sights with your current weapon
2. Look at the other weapon on the ground. You must be within "reach" of the weapon for this to work
3. Hold E (or whatever you have binded "Equip" to)
4. Repeat Steps 1-3 as many times as you desire.

As mentioned before, having more points will make accumulating speed boosts much faster.  So if you wanted to hit, say +210% movement speed, with only 1 point in Expertise, you'd have to repeat the process far more then say having Expertise at 5 (or more).

Comment: Does this work on the current patch?

Comment: I don't believe it has ever been fixed or patched

Comment: Actually, it seems that the easiest way to do it (at least on version 1.1) is by dropping the weapon while aiming-down-the-sight.

Comment: @NiteCyper If you read the answer, you'd understand.  Normally, if you have a partially filled/empty backpack, when holding E, you will automatically equip the weapon, but it'll go in your bp.  IF you have a full one though, the weapon that is currently equipped will fall to the ground when you equip the one you're looking at.  That is why I specifically said having a full BP makes this process exponentially easier.

Comment: No, I think it is you who does not understand. I did not say "equipping the weapon while ADS", I said "dropping"; your additional explanation is moot. Watch how this runner does it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2YYwM1coOU#t=50m58 . So, it seems your explanation is technically wrong: you need one weapon, minimum, and we need Axton to merely drop a weapon while ADS, not switch, though I suspect this explanation may not be sufficient either if it's doable by switching the weapon's weapon slot position in the inventory, like the weapon merge glitch.

Comment: @NiteCyper You can only drop weapons two ways: having a full backpack and trying to equip a weapon on the ground, or going into your inventory and manually hitting "drop".  This glitch is only doable if you have two guns.  If you watched that video carefully, you noticed he's using TWO guns, not one, one Bandit, the other Tediore, so I would suggest you pay attention to it. Later on in the video, it cuts to his backpack, and shows he has a full inventory, exactly what I mentioned before.

Comment: When you HOLD E to equip a weapon, normally that weapon goes into your hands right away, so you can use it.  However, IF you have a full backpack, the GAME WILL NOT ALLOW YOU to have more than what your backpack space is, so it will DROP THE WEAPON you are holding, and PICK UP THE WEAPON ON THE GROUND to avoid that issue.  You should really check what you're saying

Comment: Actually, then that makes at least three ways, because there's a button (I believe it's default -) to drop weapons without going into the inventory or swapping with a weapon on the ground. Um, perhaps you don't have it on controllers? The runner is clearly using that button because he drops  three weapons, one after the other, without swapping with anything on the ground and without going into his inventory to do so. "Exponentially easier", whereas by your assertion that there are only two ways, there is no "easier"; it is the only way. I understand your method; you don't need to repeat it.

Comment: @NiteCyper There's only two weapons, watch the video again.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was looking at a different part of the run: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2YYwM1coOU#t=1h18m37 . You're right that the runner performs the glitch with only two weapons (and only two weapon slots) when they first perform and explain the glitch.

Answer (score 2):

Axton speed glitch is done from an off-host player, this is because there is something built into the game to make connections to hosts more efficient. Using the skill Expertise a player can stack their ADS movement by throwing their gun while looking down the sights. This can be done how ever many times you wish.

This exploit can only done off-host because connecting to another player changes character saving from the Single-Player method of saving all the character data at once (including whether the player is looking down sights.) to the Multi-Player method of sending status effect and some player data to the host. (Including speed, but not whether their looking down sights. That's why it stacks when they ADS again.)